# Is it possible to implemente an ItemTemplate within a ListView?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, itemtemplate

How do I implement an ItemTemplate within a ListView?

I would like to do in my layout something like this:

[image]

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ItemTemplate for a ListView, but your example is clearly a Grid, so I would use that instead.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Text="Order Proposal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
  ... additional buttons here ...
</Grid>
```

You would probably want to create a custom control to use instead of Button, or use a ContentView that builds the custom UI you want for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Grid>
          <!-- Your item template UI -->
        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But for me better way is to use GridView:
[XLabs GridView on github](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/GridView)